# How does strcat() works internally in C?

Tags: c

Let's say I want to concatenate "A" and "B" in C, both char * arrays, I will call them a and b respectively. 
We know that in the end of a,b there is a '\0' to note the end of the word.
When I use strcat(a,b), how much space do I need in a for the function to work? 3 chars? 2 chars? 
Does strcat() adds '\0' or it is my job?

Comment: All these questions are answered in the [documentation of `strcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat).

Answer (score 0):

`strcat(a, b)` will overwrite the `\0` of `a` and append `b` including its `\0`, so the result is properly terminated. Quite obviously, the required buffer size is `strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1`.